# Can't install mongoctl

Tags: pip

I'm working on a 13" MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8.5. I'm trying to install mongoctl with the following command:

```
sudo pip install mongoctl
```

But I keep getting an error when downloading and unpacking argparse1.2.1. I've tried installing mongoctl with and without sudo but the result has been the same. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Downloading/unpacking argparse==1.2.1 (from dargparse->mongoctl)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement argparse==1.2.1 (from dargparse-   >mongoctl) (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.9.0, 0.8.0, 0.7.0, 0.6.0, 0.9.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.0, 0.2.0, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1, 0.3.0)
Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for argparse==1.2.1 (from dargparse->mongoctl)
```

I installed arparse1.1 manually but don't know how to use it for this installation. Any help is much appreciated.

-Mike

Comment: Well, did you try ``--allow-external`` as the error message suggests? ``argparse`` keeps its package on googlecode, not on PyPi, and ``pip`` disallows that by default.

Comment: Yes I used the --allow-external command when installing argparse manually. Not sure if you can use that with the command to install mongoctl though.

Comment: I do not see why not. And what do you mean, manually? Just a separate ``pip install argparse``, or downloading the source and running ``setup.py``? Because the latest version on PyPi is 1.2.1.

Comment: I just meant that I installed argparse separately. I've got argparse installed, but when I run sudo pip install mongoctl it still fails on argparse.

Comment: What error do you get when you run ``sudo pip install mongoctl --allow-external``? Is the list of versions after ``Could not find a version that satisfies`` the same? Did you try to download and install argparse 1.2.1 [from source](http://argparse.googlecode.com/files/argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz)?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar issue on 10.7.5 OS X. Instead of the --allow-external, I tried --allow-all-external and it seems to have worked. Or if you did --allow-external, I think you need to include which of the packages to allow.